# How to simplify $\arcsin(2\sin (x))$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I know that $\arcsin(\sin(x))$ would be $x$ (in the right domain). But, I'm unsure how to handle the scalar multiplication. Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: There is no "nicer" expression for this.

Comment: Why do you need such "simplification"? What are you trying to integrate?

Comment: what an answer should give you?

Comment: You could write it as $-i\ln\left(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}+\sqrt{e^{2ix}-1+e^{-2ix}}\right)$, but to me that looks worse. In fact, it also hints at *why* we can't do better than $\arcsin(2\sin x)$.

Answer (score 2):

You can write
$$\arcsin(a\sin (x))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ (2 n)!\,\, a^{2 n+1} }{4^n\,(2 n+1)\, (n!)^2}\,\sin ^{2 n+1}(x)$$

Comment: Hi, but do you remember all the formulas with your mind?  +1.

Comment: @Sebastiano. At least I try (hard !). I felt in love with infinite series $64+$ years ago. In fact, take the infinite series of $\arcsin(t)$ and make $t=a\sin(x)$. Simple, no ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Ah...there was a reason ....my sincere compliments.

Comment: @Sebastiano. Compliments for what ? My age ? My memory ? Back to serious, thanks :-)

Comment: For the answers and....for the memory 

Comment: maybe OP wrote the formulas wrong.  Maybe that was the question $\sin(2 \arcsin(x))$

Comment: @lonestudent. Who knows ?

Comment: Nobody knows.., Master. Just assumption..